# I need a dummy variable which is 1 if another variable increases and 0 if it decreases

Tags: r, dummy-variable, panel-data

I have panel data with individuals and years, and the variable of interest is deductible (which can take on either 500, 1000 or 1500). I need to create a dummy variable which is 0 if the deductible for that person increased from the previous year, 1 if it decreased and 2 if it stayed the same.

Comment: can you please show the sample data?

Comment: Something along the these lines works if you don’t mind recoding your dummy `sign(diff(my data))+1` will be 0 for decrease, 1 for no change, 2 for increase.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Here is a sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are working with panel data you want to make sure you perform the necessary difference calculation while respecting the panel structure. You can, e.g., do so with the `pdata.frame` data structure and associated operations from package `plm`.

Here is an example:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
pGrunfeld <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld, index = c("firm", "year"))

pGrunfeld[2, "value"] <- pGrunfeld[1, "value"] # manipulate data so that we have a data point for case "no change"
pGrunfeld$value_diff <- diff(pGrunfeld$value)
pGrunfeld$fac <- factor(sign(pGrunfeld$value_diff))

head(pGrunfeld$fac)
# 1-1935 1-1936 1-1937 1-1938 1-1939 1-1940 
# <NA>      0      1     -1      1      1 
# Levels: -1 0 1
```

`pGrunfeld$fac` is now a factor where level -1 symbolizes decrease, 0 no change, and 1 increase in variable `pGrunfeld$value`.